# Coq won't compute a typeclass function if the typeclass has a Prop

Tags: typeclass, coq

I'm having trouble understanding the behavior of Coq's computation (or lack thereof) of typeclass functions. Here's a minimal working example:

```
Class class1 : Set := { class_func1 : nat -> nat }.
Class class2 : Set := { class_func2 : nat -> nat
                      ; class_prop2 : forall x : nat, x = x
                      }.

Instance class1_instance : class1 := { class_func1 := S }.
Instance class2_instance : class2 := { class_func2 := S }.
Proof.
  auto.
Qed.

Compute class_func1 5.
Compute class_func2 5.
```

When I call `Compute class_func1 5.`, Coq outputs `6 : nat` as expected. However, when I call `Compute class_func2 5.`, I get

```
 = (let (class_func2, _) := class2_instance in class_func2) 5
 : nat
```

I've tried using `unfold` and `compute` on relevant terms in proof editing mode, with no results. I've also tried replacing instances of `Prop` with `Type`, with no results.

Can someone clarify why Coq won't compute a function from a typeclass if that typeclass has a `Prop` in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because you've used `Qed` instead of `Defined` to finish the definition of `class2_instance`. `Qed` renders your definition opaque, making computation impossible.

The following works:

```
Instance class2_instance : class2 := { class_func2 := S }.
Proof. trivial. Defined.

Compute class_func2 5.  (* returns 6 *)
```

This is a universal thing, it's not because of using typeclasses with `Prop`. E.g. the following definition of the identity function won't compute as well

```
Definition id (x : nat) : nat.
  exact x. Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I had no idea that `Qed` and `Defined` had such different meanings. Sorry for all the basic questions :P